# Button click handlers with arguments

Tags: svelte

What is the recommended approach for passing an argument to a svelte button click handler?

The use case is a repeating button inside an each list. From what I can tell the documentation only shows examples of how to deal with a single button where you can use a global variable to pass data. This is not as practical if you are stamping out a list of buttons in a grid.

Example:

```
{#each comments as c}
    <div class="comment-block">

    <div class="comment"> {c.text} </div>
    <!-- How can I pass c.id to the  approveComment handler? -->
    <button on:click="{approveComment}">Approve</button>
    </div>
{/each}

<script>
function approveComment() {
  // how can I pass an id to this method
}
</script>
```

One solution is to move the content of the `each` block into another component, and pass in the comment object as a prop, but I am curious if you can bind an input value to the button handler per iteration through the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `approveComment` has the event as an argument.  Change your function declaration to:

```
function approveComment(event) {
  // now you can access event.target where you can store 
  // the id from your button, e.g.:
  const id = event.target.value;
  console.log(id);
}
```

You also need to declare the c.id in the value property of your button:

```
<button on:click={approveComment} value={c.id}>Approve</button>
```